# Algorithm for 12 000 records MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, full-text-search

I use the full-text search + BOOLEAN MODE, but this not efficient. This is my code:

```
$sssql = $server_link->query("SELECT uDR.webTitulo, uDR.webDescripcion, uDR.webkeywords, uDR.weburl, SUM(uDR.priority) as SPriority
FROM (

(SELECT s1.webTitulo, s1.webDescripcion, s1.weburl, s1.webkeywords, $a as priority FROM webs s1 WHERE MATCH (webTitulo) AGAINST ('$frase'))

UNION

(SELECT s2.webTitulo, s2.webDescripcion, s2.weburl, s2.webkeywords, $b as priority FROM webs s2 WHERE MATCH (webkeywords) AGAINST ('$frase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))



UNION

(SELECT s3.webTitulo, s3.webDescripcion, s3.weburl, s3.webkeywords, $c as priority FROM webs s3 WHERE MATCH (webDescripcion) AGAINST ('$frase'))

UNION

(SELECT s4.webTitulo, s4.webDescripcion, s4.weburl, s4.webkeywords, $d as priority FROM webs s4 WHERE MATCH (weburl) AGAINST ('$frase'))) uDR

GROUP BY uDR.webTitulo, uDR.weburl, uDR.webDescripcion, uDR.webkeywords

ORDER BY SPriority DESC ");
```

$frase = Contains the searched phrase.

The code sort the records by:

1. The record with the searched phrase in Title.
2. In keywords.
3. And 4° In description and URL.

Is inefficient because ('$frase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) delivers hundreds of irrelevant records. But I need the records with 3 letters, Example: DNA, Sun, etc.

I need words with 3 letters but also relevant results.

Comment: ft_min_word_len=3; looks like you could do 2 unions instead of 4 by just using OR

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I do not use ft_min_word_len = 3, because I can not edit.

Comment: if that's a restriction of the hosting environment, then change to one appropriate for the project.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't money to pay a big VPS.So I'm looking for a solution using an algorithm. Thanks for reply.